# Starting a thread with / without delegate()

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

What is the difference between:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeFunc))
```

and:

```
new Thread( delegate() { SomeFunc();} )
```

This code gives strange outputs on my computer:

```
public class A
{
    int Num;

    public A(int num)
    {
        Num = num;
    }

    public void DoObj(object obj)
    {
        Console.Write(Num);
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        Console.Write(Num);
    }
}

/////// in void main()

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    (new Thread(new ThreadStart((new A(i)).Do))).Start(); // Line 1
    (new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() { (new A(i)).Do(); }))).Start(); // Line 2
    (new Thread(delegate() { (new A(i)).Do(); })).Start(); // Line 3
}
```

If only Line 1 is executed the output is something like:

> 0 2 3 1 5 6 4 7 8 9

which is ok but if Line 2 or 3 is executed, output is:

> 3 3 3 5 5 7 7 9 9 10

There are some multiple numbers and a 10 which is quite strange that the loop is never run with the number 10. What is the trick behind these?

Thanks.

Comment: Read this section: http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Passing_Data_to_a_Thread , Read **Lambda expressions and captured variables**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**With the delegate, you are capturing `i`.**

The difference is that with `new ThreadStart((new A(i)).Do))`, you are creating a new instance of `A` in the `for` loop with `i` as a parameter. That means that at that point, the value of `i` is taken and send to the constructor. The delegate you are sending is thus not of the creation of `A`, but you are actually sending the a delegate of the `Do` method of the instance of `A` to the constructor.

However, with `delegate() { (new A(i)).Do(); })` (both of them), you are sending a reference of `i` to the thread.

The thread then takes some time to start and meanwhile, the `for` loop goes on. By the time `i` is used in the delegate (i.e. the thread has started), the `for` loop has moved on to `3` and that's what you see. The same goes for the second and third thread. The three threads are started but wait for the starting thread to complete some work. Then the created threads kick in (thread 1, 2 and 3) and they do their work. The Windows goes back to the thread with the `for` loop and goes on to start thread 4 and 5.

Some reading material:

- http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/34/variable-capture-in-c#-with-anonymous-delegates
- https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/
- https://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Passing_Data_to_a_Thread

Comment: See also [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) by Eric Lippert for details

Comment: +1 Great explanation, just ran into this myself yesterday using the new Task.Factory.StartNew calls with an anonymous delegate in a for loop. It caused some subtle errors. In most cases everything was normal, but if the system was busy then multiple tasks used the same data.

Comment: then i have to copy the index varible myself. e.g. int temp = i; delegate() { (new A(temp)).Do();} Right?

Comment: @bahadir - Exactly. Within the for loop, before the `new Thread`, you create a copy of the variable as you describe and your problems are gone.

Comment: also i was going to ask about Task.Start() and Task.RunSynchronously(). Because these 2 had a similar situation, but assuming RunSynchronously() starts the task right in the loop,the task is run with the proper reference of the index. That is why when Start() is used the output has multiple numbers etc.

Comment: @Pieter - agreed and I add emphasis to "within the for loop".  The variable capture feature throws so many people.

Comment: You can also add: http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Passing_Data_to_a_Thread to your reading material

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first point, `delegate() { SomeFunc();}` creates a function that calls `SomeFunc()`, whereas not using `delegate()` simply uses the `SomeFunc` function directly as the `ThreadStart` method.

In your second question, you're running into the implementation details of C# anonymous functions. All three references to `i` refer to the *same* `i`, which is incremented three times. You've got a race condition between the three functions that mean `i` can be incremented several times before the started threads are run.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an implementation detail. This is pretty fundamental. An implementation detail is something the user is not to be concerned with.

Answer (score 1):

'When is the constructor for object A called?' helps answer the question.

`new ThreadStart((new A(i)).Do))`

When this line of code is executed - the constructor is called and a reference to the `.Do` function on the newly created object A is kept by the ThreadStart delegate.

In Line 2 and 3 you are using an anonymous delegate (introduced in C# 2.0).

```
delegate() { (new A(i)).Do(); })
```

The contents of the anonymous delegate is not executed until the delegate is invoked; in this case by the thread when it is assigned a time slice to do so.

The variable i is only declared once at the start of the for loop, and the delegate contents has a reference to it (delegates will do that) - when the code is executed it must grab the value of i at the time of execution.

This explains the value 10. i has a value of 10 when the loop has finished executing. If one of the threads executes after the loop has finished, it will output a 10.

To avoid the multiple numbers issue you could create a local copy of the loop variable. The delegate will keep a reference to its own version of icopy;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     int icopy = i;
     (new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() { (new A(icopy)).Do(); }))).Start();
}
```