# Thread using delegate or function name

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

Weird question.
What the difference using those piece of code?

```
class TestThread {

public void waitFunction() {
   // Some code like this.UpdateProgress()
}

public void start() {
    Thread thWaitingScraper = new Thread(waitFunction);   // Method 1

    Thread thWaitingScraper = new Thread(delegate() { waitFunction(); });   // Method 2
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No functional difference, but a typeleak can be caused in the second method.

Typeleak is caused when the compiler needs to create an implicit class behind the scene. In this case, because t`waitFunction` is a non static member of the class, the compiler needs to create a class which holds the reference to `this` class so the function can be called with the appropriate instance. Within this class it creates the anonymous method you wrote in the second method and passes it as the `Thread` delegate parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I just find another question (a bit different from mine). That question explain another problem, correlated to delegate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134229/starting-a-thread-with-without-delegate